# Partioning logs in Tomcat by virtual host and app

Tags: tomcat, log-files

How can I instruct Tomcat to hold log files for each virtual host and app separately, similar to:

```
${tomcat.home}/logs/vhost-app-date.log
```

This is under the assumption that I configure all virtual hosts to log to the console, and they are unaware of the virtual host and application name they're running under.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this as a starting point:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html

It seems you have to change to log4j and configure it there.

If you only want different access logs it is really straight forward:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html

I have not tried it with virtual hosts by myself, I use different instances.